# Java Swing form menu with hide and show functionality

Tags: java, swing

I'm kind of new on GUI programming, and I've been struggling to figure out how to implement something like the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvWsH.png]

basically I would like to have some text entries, with an arrow on the side. When clicking on the arrow, or on the text, a form would appear under it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is basically allowing the layouts to do there job.  Add all the "properties" to `JPanel` and simply hide or show it as required

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166033/how-to-prevent-boxlayout-box-from-stretching-children-components/8166223#8166223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, this is just making a container (like `JPanel`) hide or show and letting the layout managers do their job

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(); 
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.add(new JLabel("Pecka-boo"));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Show");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    panel.setVisible(!panel.isVisible());
                    btn.setText(panel.isVisible() ? "Hide" : "Show");
                }
            });

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(btn, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(panel, gbc);
            panel.setVisible(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

for some more details.

FYI: A more complex UI would have the sub forms as separate classes, this will reduce the complex (of the individual classes) and decouple the code